# Group by complex query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
STATUS  DATE    MARKET  COUNTRY ACC INCT    VOL  TOTAL
INC 7/2/2018    CHICAGO US  123456  AB  3   0.06 
DEL 7/3/2018    CHICAGO US  123456  AB  3   0.06  
INC 7/3/2018    CHICAGO US  67890   AB  3   0.06 
INC 7/6/2018    CHICAGO US  700000  CBO     25  0.5 
INC 7/11/2018   EUROPE  WG  253235  EFDX    1   0.02
INC 7/18/2018   NEWYORK US  700000  RTY     2   0.04 
INC 7/24/2018   CHICAGO US  700000  CBO     2   0.04 
INC 7/25/2018   EUROPE  WG  253235  EFDX    1   0.02
```

Under (inc, del)if I find MARKET, COUNTRY,ACC, INCT,  VOL, TOTAL to be  identical then I need to take only the third record eliminating first two records

INC 7/3/2018    CHICAGO US  67890   AB  3   0.06

My expected output is

```
STATUS  DATE    MARKET  COUNTRY ACC INCT    VOL  TOTAL <br>
INC 7/3/2018    CHICAGO US  67890   AB  3   0.06 <br>
INC 7/6/2018    CHICAGO US  700000  CBO     25  0.5<br>
INC 7/11/2018   EUROPE  WG  253235  EFDX    1   0.02<br>
INC 7/18/2018   NEWYORK US  700000  RTY     2   0.04<br>
INC 7/24/2018   CHICAGO US  700000  CBO     2   0.04<br>
INC 7/25/2018   EUROPE  WG  253235  EFDX    1   0.02<br>
```

I only have to do this in SQL in SQL server & Oracle. I would appreciate all help. Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Put up some code :)

Comment: I tried group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common table expression (CTE) to figure out which rows have offsetting "INC" and "DEL" records.  Then, select from that CTE and exclude those.  Like this:

```
WITH tmp as ( 
SELECT id.*, 
       sum(decode(status,'INC',total,'DEL',-total)) 
           over ( partition by market, country, acc, inct, vol, total) incdel 
FROM input_data id )
SELECT status, trx_date, market, country, acc, inct, vol, total
FROM   tmp 
WHERE incdel != 0;
```

Here is a full example, with test data:

```
with input_data (STATUS,  TRX_DATE,    MARKET,  COUNTRY, ACC, INCT,    VOL,  TOTAL ) AS (
SELECT 'INC', TO_DATE('7/2/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),    'CHICAGO', 'US',  123456,  'AB',  3,   0.06 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEL', TO_DATE('7/3/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),    'CHICAGO', 'US',  123456,  'AB',  3,   0.06 FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 'INC', TO_DATE('7/3/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),    'CHICAGO', 'US',  67890,   'AB',  3,   0.06  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'INC', TO_DATE('7/6/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),    'CHICAGO', 'US',  700000,  'CBO',     25,  0.5  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'INC', TO_DATE('7/11/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),   'EUROPE',  'WG',  253235,  'EFDX',    1,   0.02 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'INC', TO_DATE('7/18/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),   'NEWYORK', 'US',  700000,  'RTY',     2,   0.04  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'INC', TO_DATE('7/24/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),   'CHICAGO', 'US',  700000,  'CBO',     2,   0.04  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'INC', TO_DATE('7/25/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'),   'EUROPE',  'WG',  253235,  'EFDX',    1,   0.02  FROM DUAL ),
tmp as ( 
SELECT id.*, 
       sum(decode(status,'INC',total,'DEL',-total)) 
           over ( partition by market, country, acc, inct, vol, total) incdel 
FROM input_data id )
SELECT status, trx_date, market, country, acc, inct, vol, total
FROM   tmp 
WHERE incdel != 0;
```

Results:

```
+--------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------+-----+-------+
| STATUS | TRX_DATE  | MARKET  | COUNTRY |  ACC   | INCT | VOL | TOTAL |
+--------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------+-----+-------+
| INC    | 03-JUL-18 | CHICAGO | US      |  67890 | AB   |   3 |  0.06 |
| INC    | 24-JUL-18 | CHICAGO | US      | 700000 | CBO  |   2 |  0.04 |
| INC    | 06-JUL-18 | CHICAGO | US      | 700000 | CBO  |  25 |   0.5 |
| INC    | 25-JUL-18 | EUROPE  | WG      | 253235 | EFDX |   1 |  0.02 |
| INC    | 11-JUL-18 | EUROPE  | WG      | 253235 | EFDX |   1 |  0.02 |
| INC    | 18-JUL-18 | NEWYORK | US      | 700000 | RTY  |   2 |  0.04 |
+--------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Fantastic , THANKS VERY MUCH

Answer (score 0):

There may several way to achieve this.  You can do by doing 2 CTE.  Posting your query will help!  This query is not complete, you'll have to finalize it.  But the main idea is here.

```
;with subQry1 (
    select STATUS DATE MARKET COUNTRY ACC INCT VOL, sum(??) total,
    from table
    where ...
    group by STATUS DATE MARKET COUNTRY ACC INCT VOL    
), subQry2 (
    select STATUS DATE MARKET COUNTRY ACC INCT VOL, total,
    rownumber() over(partition by MARKET, COUNTRY,ACC, INCT, VOL, TOTAL order by MARKET, COUNTRY,ACC, INCT, VOL, TOTAL) rnk
    from subQry1
) select * from subQry2 where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Sound like `'DEL'` "deletes" an `'INC'`luded record? That indicates a `NOT EXISTS` might help.

Without knowing the actual query nor the schema I cannot give you working query just an idea how it might look like:

```
SELECT T1.STATUS,
       T1.DATE,
       T1.MARKET,
       ...
       T1.TOTAL
       FROM ELBAT T1
       WHERE T1.STATUS = 'INC'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM ELBAT T2
                                    WHERE T2.STATUS = 'DEL'
                                          AND T2.MARKET = T1.MARKET
                                          ...
                                          AND T2.TOTAL = T1.TOTAL);
```

Comment: The danger of `NOT EXISTS` in situations like this is if an identical record is INCluded, then DELeted, and then INCluded again.  I'm not sure if that's possible in the OP's design, but if it is, it is likely that the re-INCluded record should be returned in the results and a `NOT EXISTS` approach won't accomplish that.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak: Yes, that's true, thanks for the note! Well, another approach might be to "DELete" only as much records as there are `'DEL'` using a more complicated `EXISTS` or other means. Then at least some "INCluded" might "survive". But to have the right ones "survive" one must know how they're interconnected (the `DATE` maybe?), it could still "DELete" the wrong ones. It would need further knowledge of the setup to give a more definitive answer, rather then a mere sketch here.